# what is the difference between dsp.Maximum and max function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In the latest version of Matlab R2015a, I found many new functions in the DSP System Toolbox, some of these functions can be achieved using other functions as I think.

Now my question, is there a difference between such function (dsp.Maximum) and (max)? and many other like function

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/maximum.html)?  The DSP blocks are designed for the case where the data arrives incrementally.

Comment: No, Mr Voigt, it is a matlab function not a simulink block, [link](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.maximum-class.html)

Comment: On the page you link: "This object implements the algorithm, inputs, and outputs described on the Maximum block reference page"  That is why I linked you to the Maximum block documentation, which directly answers your question.